# Cypress: How does custom event handler `cy.task()` work?

Tags: cypress

I understand what [**`cy.task()`**](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task) provides. It allows Cypress developers to create an event handler with the intent outside of the Cypress workspace.

Correct me if my description is not correct.

**What I would like to understand is how `cy.task()` works within the Cypress Test Framework.**

For example, from Cypress documentation, [`cy.task()` usage](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Usage). It does what is expected, but how?

```
// in plugins file
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    log(message) {
      console.log(message)

      return null
    },
  })
}
```

The diagram below is a work in progress, and I want to add to it where **`cy.task()`** are handled:

[image: Cypress Test Framework]

Thank you